# Ajax requests ignore virtual application sub-folder name in URL for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

My application is located on the server under a separate virtual directory. To access my ASP.NET MVC application users have to go to:

```
http://server-dev/superApp
```

I have a problem with Ajax/Json server requests ignoring the "superApp" directory part. Whenever an Ajax request is made Fiddler shows 404 because instead of `http://server-dev/superApp/User/GetUsersJson` for example, `http://server-dev/User/GetUsersJson` is called (note the missing superApp name).

Example of an Ajax request:

```
function GetUsers(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/User/GetUsersJson/",
        data:{ id: id},
        datatype: 'json',
        type:'post',
        success: function (result) {
            ////Do stuff with returned result
        }        
    });      
}
```

Registered route:

```
r.Match("User/GetUsersJson", "User", "GetUsersJson");
```

Where should I look and what can I change to make sure that my application virtual folder is ALWAYS included in all URL requests ?

p.s. Please note that all Javascript/Ajax logic is kept in separate .js files so no RAZOR syntax is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using the HTML helper method ?

```
url: "@Url.ACtion("GetUsersJson","User)"
```

**EDIT** : As per the comment

You may get the Path name using the HTML Helper method and Keep that in a Global variable and access that in the external javascript file

In the view

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  var globalGetJSONPath='@Url.ACtion("GetUsersJson","User)';
</script>
```

And now you can use it in the external file like this

```
 $.ajax({
        url: globalGetJSONPath,
        data:{ id: id},
        //remaining items....

  });
```

Comment: I updated my OP with "p.s. Please note that all Javascript/Ajax logic is kept in separate .js files so no RAZOR syntax is available." just as you posted this.
So no, unfortunately this won't work.

Comment: Ahh.. this is not a bad idea!

Comment: BTW, take a notice, that in this approach, of you will be using NLB there can be some consequences. If your app on one node will return node1.example.com, but on public side there will be something like contoso.com..

Comment: I cant try it without pushing changes to the server but let me ask you... will var globalGetJSONPath='@Url.Content("~/User/GetUsersJson/")'; work as well and return the same result as the Action example above ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this stuff by passing variable to js that contains hostname+vdir. Because of heavy js url generation.
In other cases Shyju's answer is best way to solve this.

Comment: I have not found a better way than this.

Comment: I have separate controller that returns js global variables. On top of that lives custom js routing plugin. So in js code looks like $.Action("ActionName","Controller",args) or $.Uri("ActionName","Controller")

Answer (score 1):

No way to do it without some server-side code generation. Easiest thing would be defining global variable (sorry) holding you application root and initializing it somewhere in master page.

Javascript generation of route urls always was one of the messiest parts of asp.net mvc.